# Publishing outside acedemia

Tags: publishing

I am an independent mathematician looking to publish an article related to number theory.  It's not a very rigourous article but it's still interesting My first question is whow should I publish with?  Also since I am independent, I'm not getting paid by a university.  How much do journals pay for articles?

Comment: your last question is easy: you will receive $\leq \$0 $. Anyways, this question is likely better suited here http://academia.stackexchange.com/ as it's not really about mathematics per se.

Comment: And the publishers then charge exorbitant  prices.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus, *some*, shadier ones, do. Not all.

Comment: Is there a way to publish it differently or with someone else to get pay?  Pay is a big issue and working in a university isn't an option right now

Comment: Pay may be an issue, but if it's a *big* issue you're in the wrong game...

Comment: @vonbrand yeah like springer and elsevier. Do you have any idea how much they charge university for online access ?

Comment: Ok, so maybe not an article but what about a book

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered [arXiv.org](http://arxiv.org/help/submit)?

Renegade mathematician Grigori Perelman used this service to publish his proof of the poincaré  conjecture. I don't believe he was (or is) supported by any institution.

Have you considered starting a blog to share your mathematical writings? I only bring that up because you say that your paper isn't very rigorous. This might be the most appropriate format for smaller or less academic pieces of writing. You could monetize the blog, but I wouldn't expect that it would make much money.

Like others have said, there isn't money in publishing mathematical papers--outside winning a prize for proving a famous conjecture.

Comment: *There once was a Master Programmer who wrote unstructured programs. A novice programmer, seeking to imitate him, also began to write unstructured programs. When the novice asked the Master to evaluate his progress, the Master criticized him for writing unstructured programs, saying, "What is appropriate for the Master is not appropriate for the novice. You must understand Tao before transcending structure."* (The Tao of Programming, 3.2)